# with qualifying of any of the return sattement do the loop break groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Do the loop terminates when it qualifies the return statement? even when value is null?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to be answered with any kind of certainty. Were I to hazard a guess, however, I'd bet you're referring to control statements within a '.each' loop?

If so, the short answer is: No, return (or break) does not terminate the loop.  The only way to do so is via throwing an exception within the loop à la:

```
try{
    (1..10).each{ n->
        println n
        if (n == 5) throw new Exception()
       }
}        
catch(Exception){}
```

But, this is a total abomination. Use a for or while loop instead.

**See also:** [returning from closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765605/how-does-one-return-from-a-groovy-closure-and-stop-its-execution)

If I'm off the mark, perhaps you could post some code exemplifying your topic?